# Eureka client instances are not unregister from eureka server properly

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka

When I enable SelfPreservation on eureka server, whenever eureka client instance is down its not removed from the eureka server registry and I am getting following message in RED COLOR:

> EMERGENCY! EUREKA MAY BE INCORRECTLY CLAIMING INSTANCES ARE UP WHEN THEY'RE NOT. RENEWALS ARE LESSER THAN THRESHOLD AND HENCE THE INSTANCES ARE NOT BEING EXPIRED JUST TO BE SAFE.

When I checked in google and SO, I found that we have to disable the SelfPreservation. So updated the config as below:

```
eureka.server.enableSelfPreservation=false
```

Now its removing from the registry but I am getting following message in RED COLOR:

> THE SELF PRESERVATION MODE IS TURNED OFF.THIS MAY NOT PROTECT INSTANCE EXPIRY IN CASE OF NETWORK/OTHER PROBLEMS.

What is the correct configuration?

Comment: The first warning is shown because 85% of the microservices that were registered on Eureka were down. When that happens, Eureka "thinks" that it itself is down, rather than those services, and hence the big warning. Nobody says you have to disable this feature, but if you do, then you indeed get a warning message that you disabled it, which could cause some side effects as mentioned before. Both configurations are correct depending on what you want, so I'm having difficulties at understanding your question.